# How can I transcode "faster playback speed" videos?

Tags: audio, video, vlc-media-player, transcode

I'd like to transcode a video to have faster playback speed, for use on mobile devices / chromecast. VLC has this capability, but it seems to only work during playback. For example, if I use the following command line,

```
vlc -I dummy -vvv "${input}" \
    --rate=1.0 \
    --audio-time-stretch \
    --sout-x264-preset faster \
    --sout-x264-crf=31 \
    --sout \
    "#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mp3,ab=128}:file{dst=$output}" \
    vlc://quit
```

Adjusting the `--rate` parameter seems not to work with transcoding--the audio seems to be not present. It does work with basic playback.

Has anyone gotten this to work? (I'm doing it for Coursera lectures FWIW). Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ffmpeg` has a lot of options. I bet you could use it to achieve desired result and persist them to a new file.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "for use on mobile devices"? See the linked question.

Comment: Some mobile players don't have the "2x/3x/4x" playback feature that VLC does normally. I don't think the linked question is the same; `ffmpeg` is deprecated now too (on Ubuntu at least)